# Merging a list of dataframes with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would merge a list of dataframes into one, by filling NaN values columns in the same row. The dataframes have the same index as well.

df

```
        A       B
0       Red     Blue
1       Green   Red
```

df1

```
        A       B    Value1  Value2
0       Red     Blue    1.0   NaN
1       Green   Red     NaN   0.2
```

df2

```
       A        B     Value1    Value2
1      Green    Red    3.0      NaN
0      Red      Blue   NaN      0.15
```

Code

```
df_list = [df1, df2]

df_final = pd.merge(df, df_list, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But got this error `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'list'> was passed`

Expected Output

```
        A      B    Value1  Value2
0       Red    Blue   1     0.15
1       Green  Red    3     0.20
```

Comment: `df_list` is not a data frame, it is a list of data frames...

Comment: `df_list` full name would be `list_of_dataframes`, you are trying to `pd.merge` on list and dataframe. may be you need `pd.concat[df_list]` before the `pd.merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeatedly call [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

df_final = reduce(pd.DataFrame.combine_first, df_list, df)
```

which starts with `df` as the initial value and then accumulatively invokes `combine_first` with frames from `df_list` to give a final frame.

```
>>> df_final

       A     B  Value1  Value2
0    Red  Blue     1.0    0.15
1  Green   Red     3.0    0.20
```